# Can jQuery Submit function send hidden field value to the next page?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the hidden field to the next page using PHP's `$_POST` and submit the function via jQuery, but it does not work.

#### Part of CSS OOP

```
   <ul>
        <li class="selectable" id="cakeType-<?= $cake->id ?>">
         <a href="?cakeType=<?php echo ($cake->id); ?>" title="Selecteer">
          <?php if ($cake == $order->cakeType){?><span class="checked"></span><?php } ?>
           <img src="data/<? echo $cake->id ?>.jpg" alt="" width="50"     height="50" /></a>
       </li><?php } ?></ul>
```

#### My form

```
 <form  id="formhide" method="post">
            <input name="img" type="text" value="" id="hiddenimg" action="stap2.php"/>
            </form>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){  
 $('a img').click(function(e) {
  var photo=$(this).attr('src');    
  $("#div1 img:last-child").remove() 
  $('#div1'). append('<img src="' + photo + '" />') ;
  $('#hiddenimg').val(photo);
  console.log(  $('#hiddenimg').val()  );
  e.preventDefault();   
});
$('a.nextStep').click(function() {
    if (debug) { alert('submit!') };
    $('#formhide').submit();


});
```

#### Next page as the form gets submited

```
$img=$_POST['img'];
echo $img; // the value of my hidden field does not show up i get error msg
$_SESSION['img']=$img;
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Can you send us the form code? The post should send any piece of the form based on the name="insertName" and the corresponding value, whether hidden or not.

Comment: Can you run this after the code and tell us what it gives you?

console.log(  $('#hiddenimg').val()  );

I see you have it included, does it show up on your console already?

Comment: Where is your form's `action` attribute? That should be set to whatever URI you're posting to.

Comment: if you do an: 
alert($('#hiddenimg').val());

in your click handler, does it have a value?

Comment: also:  if you want it to be hidden, but it in a <input type="hidden" />, instead of a hidden text field.

Comment: i did alert, it did not show up any thing, therefor i changed hidden into text so i see if it can get the value of img it does show up the name of every img but cannot sent it to the next page

Comment: The action should go on the form

Comment: i did try both with alert and console nothing comes up but if i insert a submit button into the html form then it works fine only with jQuery i get no result

Comment: how is the form submitted, i.e. is there a submit button anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

jQuery.noConflict()